# What is the explicit behaviour of 'docker restart'?

Tags: docker

The docker docs just say this command will "restart one or more containers". But that isn't clear enough for me.

Is this effectively;

```
if (container.isRunning) {
   docker stop container
   docker start container
} else {
   docker start container
}
```

?

ie. if the container isn't running, it will be `docker start`'ed, and if it is it will be stopped and then started again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Effectively, yes, with some additional considerations to care for interactions between different features such as to avoid deleting a container started with AutoRemove `--rm` (normally they are autoremoved on stop but should not be on restart)

See the implementation here: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/de7172b600d5fbdf6d8861116bf5491d17d609be/daemon/restart.go#L37